# автотесты проблема с получением элемента

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, автоматизация

При загрузке веб-страницы необходимый мне текст появляется с задержкой. Сначала вместо него есть три точки, через какое-то время появляется сам текст.
Ожидание через WebDriver wait не работает.

То, что видно сразу при загрузке страницы:
Эл. почта: ...
То, что загружается чуть позже и, собственно, нужно мне:
Эл. почта: tram-param@gde-to.tut

```
private final WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(DriverSingleton.getDriver(), 10);

private final WebElement companyEmail = wait.until(
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Эл. почта:')]")));
```

Через Assert проверяю полученный текст (емэйл) с регулярным выражением. Тест, естественно фэйлится, так как не получаю валидный емэйл.
Подскажите, как дождаться загрузки элемента.

Comment: выяснил, что фактически на сайте есть защита от ботов, не понимаю, как её обойти

Answer (score 0):

Ожидание у вас работает, вы же ждете тег `li`, а он у вас в разметке есть сразу же при загрузке страницы.
Как вариант использовать метод, который бы проверял в цикле текущее значение и пока оно равно, в вашем случае, "..." цикл не завершался бы.

Напишу на C#, думаю написать на Java проблем у вас не составит.

```
private void TestMethod()
{
    ...

    var selector = By.Id("email");
    WaitElementChangeText(selector, "...", 15);

    ...
}

private static void WaitElementChangeText(By selector, string text, int maxWaitSeconds)
{
    var element = _driver.FindElement(selector);

    // Берем текущую дату и добавляем таймаут - это максимальное время ожидания
    var maxDate = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(maxWaitSeconds);

    // Обновляем значение элемента, пока оно эквивалетно переданному ("...") и проверяем время
    while (element.Text.Equals(text) && maxDate.Ticks > DateTime.Now.Ticks)
    {
        element = _driver.FindElement(selector);
    }
}
```